# Show that $\lim s_{n}=+\infty $ and $ k>0,then $ $\lim(ks_{n})=+\infty $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

Please check my proof and point the mistake :)

For $M> 0$ there exist $T$ such that for all $n\geq T$

Consider $S_{n}> \frac{M}{k}$

for $n>T$, we choose $T\geq \frac{M}{k}$,it follow that $kT\geq M$

Because $n>T$, we get $n> \frac{M}{k}$ that is $kT\geq M$

Therefore if $\lim s_{n}=\infty $ then $\lim (ks_{n})=\infty $

Comment: $|k|=k.$ since it is positive.

Comment: You either multiply each epsilon by k or divide it by k (I don't remember)

Comment: I'm not sure you mean  M is epsilon or not ,but I write it as fraction then cancel it by multiply by k on both sides of inequality